# How to use HTML5 history push state instead of window.location.hash?

Tags: javascript, html

Now i am currently using window.location.hash for history management like below, how can i replace this with HTML5 history push state.

```
        var  stateHistory = []; 

        function changeHistory(page) {

            var l = stateHistory.length,
                state = window.location.hash;

            if (l === 0) {
                stateHistory.push(state);        
                return;
            }
            if (state === stateHistory[l - 2]) {
                stateHistory.pop();       
            } else {
                stateHistory.push(state);          
            }

        };
```

Comment: You can find a guide on how to use the history API in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and [various](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) [other](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/) [sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+history+api). You just have to *search* for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use HTML5 history pustate function [More Info......](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

```
    function changeHistory(page) {

           window.history.pushState({page:""+page},""+page);       
    };
```